# How to update a record on mongo db through restapi?

Tags: mongodb, rest, express, vue.js, fetch

Everytime I click on the update button an error message appears which says Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/update' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

The front end code:

```
<form id="sweets">

ID: <input v-model="id" type="text" name="id"><br>
Sweet: <input v-model="sweetname" type="text" name="name"><br>
Price: <input v-model="price" type="text" name="price"><br>
<button v-on:click="update">Update</button>

</form>
```

The client side coding:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        price: ""
    },

    methods: {
        update() {
            const sweetscollection = {
                id: this.id,

                name: this.name,
                price: this.price
            };
            const options = {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json"
                }
            };
            fetch("http://localhost:3000/update", options).then(response => {
                console.log("success", response);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The server side:

```js
app.put("/update", (req, res, next) => {
    req.collection.update(
        { _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) },
        { $set: req.body },
        { safe: true, multi: false },
        (e, result) => {
            if (e) return next(e);
            res.send(
                result.result.n === 1 ? { msg: "success" } : { msg: "error" }
            );
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Your client-side code appears to be hitting `/update` route when it should be hitting `/sweets/sweets/:id` route. Also, your client-side code does not seem to be passing the updated `sweetscollection` along with the **PUT** request that you're sending.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried changing it to /update route but it doesn't seem to replace the data. It's no working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see the place, where you are sending data to the backend. You set `sweetscollection`, but where do you send it to the backend? To send data via *fetch()*, you'd need to set the **body** property of the fetch request (*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch*)
2. You also have a **CORS** issue - that means that the server "doesn't want" to share resources with your frontend code. You have to take care of that by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your **Express** server, by adding:

Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // Handle the post for this route
});
```

*Source: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html*

More about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206671/discussion-on-answer-by-muka-gergely-how-to-update-a-record-on-mongo-db-through).

Comment: In the server's view/index.html you see the two buttons